# Methods for Functions

Tags: java, loops, methods, java.util.scanner

**Note: Desire to move this to Code Review with a clearer structure for answer and my modified code which was very similar to the answer besides calcmin method.**

I'm trying to break this code up into multiple methods and I was successful with the first bit but the other two I can't seem to figure out.

With the second method I was trying to make it so it would ask the user for an integer and continually prompts them until a proper integer is entered.

With the third method I was trying to make it so that it takes three integer parameters and returns the minimum value of those parameters.

I'd really appreciate the help on this. I've looked through examples in my book and can't seem to get it.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MinOfThreeInts 
{
    public static void intro ()
    {
        System.out.println("This program determines the minimum of three ints");
        System.out.println("It gracefully reports errors when erroneous data is entered ");
        System.out.println("For example, if you type in 'abc' when this program asked for an int");
        System.out.println("the program will report the error & ask for another int");
        System.out.println("Try giving it bad input ! \n\n");

    }
    public static void readInt (int value1, int value2, int value3)
    {
        System.out.print(" Please enter an integer value ");
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = console.nextLine();
        Boolean goodInt;
        int parsedValue = 0;
        goodInt = false;
        while (!goodInt)
        {
            try
            {
                parsedValue = Integer.parseInt(input);
                goodInt = true;
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException ex)
            {
                System.out.print("    Invalid input, please enter Int ");
                input = console.nextLine();
            }
        }
        value1 = parsedValue;

        // Get the second integer

        System.out.print(" Please enter an integer value ");
        input = console.nextLine();
        goodInt = false;
        while (!goodInt)
        {
            try
            {
                parsedValue = Integer.parseInt(input);
                goodInt = true;
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException ex)
            {
                System.out.print("      Invalid input, please enter Int ");
                input = console.nextLine();
            }
        }
        value2 = parsedValue;

        // Get the third integer

        System.out.print(" Please enter an integer value ");
        input = console.nextLine();
        goodInt = false;
        while (!goodInt)
        {
                try
            {
                parsedValue = Integer.parseInt(input);
                goodInt = true;
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException ex)
            {
                System.out.print("     Invalid input, please enter Int ");
                input = console.nextLine();
            }
        }
        value3 = parsedValue;
    }

    public static void calcMin (min)
    {
        int min = value1;
        if (value2 < min)
        {
            min = value2;
        }
        if (value3 < min)
        {
            min = value3;
        }

    // Now report the results
    System.out.println(" The minimum value of the three ints is " + min);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        value1 = readInt(console);
        value2 = readInt(console);
        value3 = readInt(console);

        min = calcMin(value1,value2,value3); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Given that your code works, and you just want to refactor it, your question might be better suited to the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of issues. I refactored your code and added comments, I stayed close to your code in order to give you insights on where you can improve.

First, the code:

```
   import java.util.Arrays;
   import java.util.Collections;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class MinOfThreeInts {

        //the main method, things start here
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            //initialize a new scanner that the application will use
            Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

            //print the intro
            intro();

            //read the values one by one and save them in a variable
            int value1 = readInt(console);
            int value2 = readInt(console);
            int value3 = readInt(console);

            //calculate the minimum and save it in the min variable
            int min = calcMin(Arrays.asList(value1,value2,value3));

            // Now report the results
            System.out.println(" The minimum value of the three ints is " + min);

        }

        /**
         * Reads an integer from the given console
         */
        public static int readInt(Scanner console) {

            System.out.print(" Please enter an integer value ");

            //read the input
            int parsedValue = 0;
            boolean goodInt = false;

            //as long as we don't find a valid number
            while (!goodInt)
            {
                try
                {
                    //read the input
                    String input = console.nextLine();

                    //try to parse the value
                    parsedValue = Integer.parseInt(input);

                    //set goodInt to true so that the while loop will end
                    goodInt = true;
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException ex)
                {
                    //if the provivded value was not an integer, print a message and return to the start of the while loop
                    System.out.print("      Invalid input, please enter Int ");
                }
            }

            return parsedValue;

        }

        /**
         * calculates the minimum of a list of values
         */
        public static int calcMin (List<Integer> values) {

            //find the minimum and return the value
            return Collections.min(values);

        }

        /**
         * prints an intro message
         */
        public static void intro () {
            System.out.println("This program determines the minimum of three ints");
            System.out.println("It gracefully reports errors when erroneous data is entered ");
            System.out.println("For example, if you type in 'abc' when this program asked for an int");
            System.out.println("the program will report the error & ask for another int");
            System.out.println("Try giving it bad input ! \n\n");

        }

    }
```

Now, on what you can do to improve:

- **compile** the code does not compile, always take care your code compiles and then slightly edit it until it compiles again
- **scope** your code has multiple declared integers, the problem was that the values were not visible in other methods, if you declare a variable, say int value1 in some method, another method will not be able to see it. If you have another int value1 in that other method, it will only be visible in that specific method and it will actually be another variable
- **arguments vs return types** methods *take* arguments and *return* something. The arguments are the input of the method and the returned value is the result of the method. Take for example your method: `public static void readInt (int value1, int value2, int value3)`. This is a method that should read an integer value from the console. However, this method signature says it takes 3 integers as parameter. These integers would be passed by value, since they are primitive types, so you can not pass them, then fill them and then return them. There is also no return type, so the method is not returning something. Since the integer parameters value1, value2 and value3 are only visible in the method scope, you will loose your data. Compare with the new signature:  `public static int readInt(Scanner console)`. This method takes a console to read from as a parameter and returns an integer, the number that has been read. This method encapsulates the retry.